# adding recent open document list in non document based app

Tags: macos, dock

I have observed that some of the applications like xcode show a list of recently opened documents in their dock menu like in the image below. I wanted to show similar recently opened docs for my application but I not able to find any resource on how to achieve this. Can someone help on how to do this?

[image]